# Jquery validation not working on Document.ready()

Tags: jquery, validation

I am using [ketchup plugin](http://demos.usejquery.com/ketchup-plugin/) for my form validation. I have an a set of input element contained in a div that act as a prototype. That is, the said div is cloned and appended in a parent div when an 'add' button is pressed . for example that if I press it, say, 5 times the said prototype div will be cloned five times and appended to the parent div. Now, since I don't want the elements in prototype divs to be validated, I am adding the 'data-validation' attribute in the input elements before appending the cloned div to the parent div. The problem is, apart from the add button, the cloning function is also called at the document.ready() function of jquery, it makes an AJAX call to the server , gets some data and appends the specified number of divs in parent.Since the validation.ketchup function (the function to valiate) is also called in document.ready, my validation are for some reason not working on these divs. but if I place a 'check' button and call the validation function on its click event, the validation works...but since validation does not work on document.ready, the messages are not shown on blur event, which is what I want...Can anybody give me any ideas??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the form validation is an event that should be fired when the user interacts with a form, therefore should only be triggered on events such as form submit, textbox change, radio click etc

Put simply validation wouldn't work on `$(document).ready` because there is nothing to validate. So put your validation checks in a function of some sort, or at least only call it when the user drives an event.

Comment: Hi, 
Thanks for the reply. I do understand that the validation function should be called in an event. But the is the real trouble. By placing the validation function in $(document).ready(), the validation works for on blur event of ALL my elements having a data-validation attribute. Can you please tell me how I can achieve the same result ?

Comment: As it turns out, I just had to use call the function at the correct event. Here I did that on onLoad event of body...and now it works fine...thakyou!

Comment: This answer and the comments of @Adnan are pure gold!
$(document).ready() won't work, but $(window).on('load' ... does the job!
Thanks a lot!